# Oracle SQL join the same table

Tags: oracle, join, outer-join

I have a table (MyTable) with this columns:
point
alarm
load_id
countAlarms
...

and I use this query:

```
select point, decode(alarm,0,'new','rec') NewRec, sum (countAlarms) total_alarms, load_id from MyTable
where 1=1 
--and load_id = (select max(load_id) from MyTable ) -0
group by point, decode(alarm,0,'new','rec'), load_id
order by 1, 2
)
```

to receive something like this:

```
point1 new 1200 111113
point1 rec 6000 111113
point2 new 1220 111113
point2 rec 3000 111113
point3 new 3220 111113
point3 rec 1000 111113
point1 new 1300 111112
point1 rec 6300 111112
point3 new 1220 111112
point3 rec 1100 111112
point1 new 1300 111111
point1 rec 6300 111111
point2 new 1120 111111
point2 rec 3100 111111
point3 new 1220 111111
point3 rec 1100 111111
....
```

what i need is this:

```
point   newRec      point   point   point
---------------------------------------
point1  new         1200    1300    1300
point1  rec         6000    6300    6300
point2  new         1220            1120
point2  rec         3000            3100
point3  new         3220    1220    1220
point3  rec         1000    1100    1100
```

I have tried with a full outer join but it don't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to [`pivot`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/statements_10002.htm#sthref6786) your result set, rather than join it to itself. Assuming you're on Oracle 11g or higher you can do this natively:

```
select * from (
  select point, decode(alarm,0,'new','rec') NewRec, countAlarms, load_id
  from MyTable
)
pivot (
  sum(countAlarms) as alarms
  for (load_id) in (111113 as a, 111112 as b, 111111 as c)
)
order by 1, 2;
```

Which with sample data matching your output above gives:

```
POINT  NEWREC   A_ALARMS   B_ALARMS   C_ALARMS
------ ------ ---------- ---------- ----------
point1 new          1200       1300       1300 
point1 rec          6000       6300       6300 
point2 new          1220                  1120 
point2 rec          3000                  3100 
point3 new          3220       1220       1220 
point3 rec          1000       1100       1100
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1f77d6/1).

You have to know the values you're pivoting on though; it isn't clear if you know the load IDs in advance, but the commented-out load ID filter in your original query suggests you might not. If you always want the three (or any fixed number of) highest load IDs then that can be achieved by modifying the inner query and the pivot criteria, e.g. with an analytic `dense_rank()` pseudo-column:

```
select * from (
  select point, decode(alarm,0,'new','rec') NewRec, countAlarms,
    dense_rank() over (partition by null order by load_id desc) as rnk
  from MyTable
)
pivot (
  sum(countAlarms) as alarms
  for (rnk) in (1 as a, 2 as b, 3 as c)
)
order by 1, 2;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1f77d6/2).

Comment: Alex, just for fun :-), no pun intended http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246331/main-page-still-shows-the-name-of-last-poster-even-after-he-deletes-his-post

Comment: Haha...lol :-) sorry to post as a comment here, I wish SO offers a private messaging.

Comment: @UserRaspberry - quite a useful summary of how it works [here](http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php). Lots more [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#CHDCEJJE) of course.